How do I add linebreaks in Markdown list but not when rendered?
When writing Markdown, generally newlines are not a problem:
This is a very long sentence in a short
paragraph, or maybe a paragraph made of
a single very long sentence.

This is an intended separate paragraph.

should be the same as
This is a very long sentence in a short paragraph, or maybe a paragraph made of a single very long sentence.

This is an intended separate paragraph.

But apparently not when using lists:
Here is some text:
- Short title:
    - This is a very long sentence in a short
    paragraph, perhaps.

is not the same as
Here is some text:
- Short title:
    - This is a very long sentence in a short paragraph, perhaps.

Having the linebreak results in it being embedded in the list item.
I would like to continue using linebreaks for readability in my Markdown source (max line length 120) without impacting its look when rendered (e.g., on GitHub, or rendered to a PDF). Is it possible? If not, is there a better way to have a short title followed by a longer explanation, without an entire heading?

Could you add more information on where this is not rendering as you expect? On GitHub your markdown renders as you expect it to.

I was using an online editor (stackedit), it renders the linebreaks there. Indeed on GitHub and VSCode it renders as expected

I cannot reproduce the problem you are having as for me:
This
Here is some text:
- Short title:
    - This is a very long sentence in a short
    paragraph, perhaps.

And this
Here is some text:
- Short title:
    - This is a very long sentence in a short paragraph, perhaps.

Is producing the same result of
Here is some text:

Short title:

This is a very long sentence in a short
paragraph, perhaps.



I think you might have some extra spaces at the end of - This is a very long sentence in a short because two spaces at the end of a line is rendered as a line break.

"Is producing the same result" - the HTML source code this produces still contains the line break though - it simply gets condensed to a single space character, as per HTML's rules. OP's trouble appears to be with other methods of rendering the results, where this does not apply (or not correctly.)

Huh, well that's embarrassing. I just tried out a different renderer (VSCode) from the one I was using (stackedit) and it does indeed render the same in there.

Tried this on stackedit and it seems to be a problem in just stackedit since it is rendering all the line breaks in the source both inside and outside the list.

I guess I now know not to use that editor. Arguably I should've tested on GitHub first, but then again I find it's more often I'm doing something wrong instead of the tool being broken.

Yeah, stackoverflow only exists because we know we are doing something wrong, in this case it was just not testing stuff.
